# What can we say about the sum of independent random variables with finite expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Currently reading up on some measure-theoretic probability, and got stuck on the following problem from an earlier exam in a probability theory course.

### Problem 3

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with finite variance $\text{Var}(X_k) < \infty$. Prove that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n \leq x)
$$
can only take three values. Which 3 values? Find conditions under which the limit takes each of these three values.

### My attempt

So far, I've been able to show that $E[X_k] > 0$ implies that the above limit is 0 by using the law of large numbers. In the case where $E[X_k] < 0$, a similar argument show that the limit goes to 1 instead. I have no idea what happens in the case where $E[X_k] = 0$.

How can one show that there are only 3 possibilities, and find conditions for when the last possibility occurs?

Comment: Central limit theorem: $\sqrt n(\hat \mu-\mu)\Rightarrow \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$

Comment: @AndrewZhang Thank you, I think I got it now!